# Bluetooth wasn't identifying any of my devices, now not working at all

Tags: 18.04, drivers, bluetooth, dell, xps

I recently bought a Dell xps 13 9300 which arrived a few days ago. It has ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled on it. After starting it up the first time and trying to turn bluetooth on to connect it to my headphones under settings, it couldn't find any of my devices in the search. After downloading this package from github using these commands

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15.git
sudo dkms add ./newbtfix-4.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

bluetooth won't turn on at all now, on top of that there's problems when booting up, sometimes I'm faced with a blank screen and I have to re-enter my password.

[image]

I deleted the package but I still have the same issue. Here is the output from the

```
sudo rfkill list
```

command

```
: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

also the

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

command I cannot paste the results of here as there are too many characters.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: YOU should read through the log dump, line by line, and determine whether the line is information,  warning, error, or debug.

Comment: Does it show up in `sudo lshw -C network` or `sudo journalctl  -b 0` (read, don't post).

Comment: @waltinator what should I look for exactly?